# Can anyone please tell where is "Browse foreign values" option is located in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to know where "Browse foreign values" option is located on phpMyAdmin ?
If anyone has seen it before please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more context might help us; where did you learn of "Browse foreign values"? If you're following a tutorial that mentioned it, it would help us to see it to understand the context of where you are and what you're doing; if you've seen mention of it in phpMyAdmin or the phpMyAdmin documentation, then we should improve the documentation to make it clear what we're talking about.

Anyway, I think [FAQ 6.21](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_6.21) has the answers you seek.